# Get Downloadable LInk title from link id in Magento

Tags: magento

I created one module in which I have downloadable link id but I don't know how to get title of  link in magento. I am using Magento 1.7+ and I am getting download Id from Quote item

Such as

```
  $productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

  foreach($productOptions['links'] as $option){
    ..
    ..
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I know in some instances you can call $link->getLinkTitle(), but I don't know whether that works with the collection you have there.

Comment: @TonyTheJet Yes I tried to find answer but do not get any support for external source. Also I have limited knowledge of magento at that time. Also this is for downloadable product where link require to be purchase hence it was special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following code :

```
$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());            

if (isset($options['options']) && is_array($options['options'])) 
{
    foreach ($options['options'] as $key=>$op) 
    {
        if (isset($op['label'])) $options['options'][$key]['label'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($op['label']);
        if (isset($op['value'])) $options['options'][$key]['value'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($op['value']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to get the link title

```
$links=Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addTitleToResult()
        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$_product->getId()));

foreach($links as $link){
    echo "<a href='" . $link->getLink_url() . "'>Download " . $link->getDefault_title() . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you to get downloadable link title by link id.

```
    $links=Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addTitleToResult()
   ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.link_id',array('eq'=>$link_id));
    return $links->getFirstItem()->getDefaultTitle();
```